# Is there any way to define bracket operator for pointer of a class?

Tags: c++

Essentially, I made a class, gave it a bracket operator but since Its much better for me to have it as a pointer rather than a field i have to use it like this:

```
auto* p = new wannabeArray();
(*p)[1] = 5;
```

Is there any way to make p[1] work properly?

Comment: why exactly is it "much better for me to have it as a pointer rather than a field"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of `p[1]` is already defined by the language. It can't be changed for a pointer. You can define that only for user defined types.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* make a class to hold the pointer, e.g.

```
class wannabeHolder: boost::noncopyable
{
    wannabeArray *p;
public:
    wannabeHolder(wannabeArray *p): p(p) {}

    wannabeArray *operator->() { return p; }
    wannabeArray::value_type &operator[](size_t n) { return (*p)[n]; }
};
```

However you are reinventing part of the wheel here, or at least some of the spokes. As Alf suggests, there are probably better ways to organize your code than to do something like this.